# How to wait until operations within a foreach loop are completed before iterating again in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task

I currently am running the following code:

```
async Task Method() 
{ 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Row) 
    {
        // Do Something
    }

    await Task.Delay(120000);
}
```

However this obviously does only wait for a certain time. Now I am wondering how to change it, so that it will wait until one iteration inside the foreach loop is completely independent of time to then start another iteration until the loop/loops are completed.

I have read about `Task.WhenAll()` but I don't get it. I could also put my `Method()` in a foreach loop if it is required or preferred.

Comment: Add the "do something" part. As is we only can see that the delay is the only async part in that method, which makes the question senseless.

Answer (score 3):

If the code inside the loop is synchronous, then the statements inside of the loop will complete before you get to your awaited delay. If you have asynchronous statements inside of the loop then you want to await those to ensure they complete before processing the next line.

If you want to ensure that your "Method" finish completes before it is called again, you want to ensure that the call to `Method()` is awaited or otherwise Waited.

You don't normally add things like `Task.Delay` in code to force it to delay until other code has executed. That would be used for testing out waiting behaviour. Code should take only as long as it needs to, and when it comes to asynchronous code, as long as it is awaited properly, there is no need to put in things like delays.

Asynchronous code allows your code, or processes around your code to manage a degree of parallelism. It is not a silver bullet to solve problems like "my code is taking too long", and you do need to be very careful with parallelism when it comes to references to classes that are not thread safe. (I.e. EF DbContexts)

To avoid confusion, you should also always suffix your `async` methods with "Async" to make it crystal clear they are asynchronous and should be awaited. I.e. `public Task MethodAsync()`.

So in summary,

Remove `Task.Delay()`.

If your loop makes calls to `async` calls, `await` them. Synchronous calls will be done sequentially so the loop will already wait for them to complete.

Ensure that if the caller of MethodAsync is `async` itself, the call to MethodAsync should be `await`ed. If the caller of MethodAsync is synchronous and you cannot use `await`, then <s>Wait the returned Task.</s> Just don't, this is a rabbit hole you don't want to look down, make a synchronous version of the code.

Comment: I didn't have a compiler to check on the Wait flavours as I recalled there was a WaitAndUnwrapException to handle aggregate exceptions thrown in async code, and the ability to set timeouts, but that does appear to have changed with .Net Core.  I see there still isn't a tidy way to call `async` code from a sync method that handles deadlocking and AggregateException, so removed. :)